# Hibernate @DynamicUpdate not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to replace the deprecated @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
with 
@DynamicUpdate(true)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(true)

It just does not work. I am using hibernate version 4.3.5.Final and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api 1.0.0.Final

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find answer for this?

Comment: The issue turned out to be that the jboss version 7.1.1. that I was using was using hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final, which does not have @DynamicUpdate(true) @SelectBeforeUpdate(true). Only way is to upgrade the version of jboss.